# When converting a pool to salt water, should the pool lights be replaced?

Tags: pool

We are planning to convert our pool to a salt water pool. We have 3 quotes.. All 3 suggested different systems...Hayward, Pentair and Jandy.  We want to know if the salt water filtration system will rust the pool lights? Should we replace them? Should we seal them?

Answer (score 1):

The key to any pool regardless of sanitization or oxidation method used is to keep the water balanced.  This means keeping pH, total alkalinity, hardness and total dissolved solids in-check.  If the water is not balanced then you will overtime do damage to your pool and equipment regardless.  Well balanced water should not be corrosive.  There are lots of other metal parts in your pool other than your lights - ladders, heat exchanger (in a gas heater), etc.

Your lights should already be sealed, if they were not, you would be losing water through your lights.

Comment: On StackExchange, if you like the answer, you should click on the Up arrow in order to vote for it.

Comment: Salt water will tend to keep the "levels" more balanced, since there is slow addition of chlorine and not much Human Error, however, it also creates a vapour from the pool which aides corrosion of Iron components. if you have any metal close to the pool, it will start to corrode faster.